# flex get contents of arraycollection as string

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to get the contents of an arraycollection to print out using my debug function (which takes a string). Anyone know how to do this? I would like it would be rather easy but can't seem to find a way...I get the word "Object" printed a lot of the time.

Comment: Can you add the function that you're using, and the source of the objects being passed to it?

Comment: hey Dan M. I tried a bunch of functions but none really seemed to work. The object being used to create the ArrayCollection are XML nodes from an HTTPService. I got it working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method should get you what you need:

```
public static function arrayCollectionToString( arr:ArrayCollection ):String
{
    var toRet:String = "[";
    for each( var obj:Object in arr ) {
        toRet += obj.toString() + ", ";
    }
    toRet += "]";
    return toRet;
}
```

If you stick this in the same class as your debug method, you could then use it as follows:

```
SomeDebugClass.dbgMessage( SomeDebugClass.arrayCollectionToString( myArrayCollection ) );
```

Comment: This will have a trailing comma at the end of the list. Use the answer below from sharvey.

Answer (score 10):

It's a lot cleaner to do:

```
var str:String = '['+myArrayCol.source.join(', ')+']';
```

the source property of an ArrayCollection is an Array, so all the usual functions are available.

Answer (score 0):

Default is allready coma separated

```
array.toString()
```

Comment: This is if you're accessing the 'source' property (which is an Array) on the ArrayCollection object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ObjectUtil.toString(arrayCollection);
```